# Is it possible to measure the ac noised filtered by a bypass capacitor in an oscilloscope?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

Is it possible to measure the ac noised filtered by a bypass capacitor in an oscilloscope? Because when we put the probes around the capacitor are we also not measuring the voltage around the resistor (Re) as they are in parallel?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You talk about a bypass cap in an oscilloscope, and yes the resistor and cap in the diagram are in parallel so you must measure the circuit as a whole.

Comment: Within some limitations, a current probe can be used for this. But it's not obvious that the example schematic is even a good example of what the text is relating to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to measure the ac noised filtered by a bypass capacitor in an oscilloscope?

Yes, it is possible, but there are some nuances and considerations.

Bypass capacitors are used to filter out AC noise, especially at high frequencies, on power rails. They provide a low-impedance path for the AC noise to ground, effectively "shorting" the noise to ground.

When you're trying to measure the noise filtered by a bypass capacitor, you'll typically want to measure:

1. The noise on the power rail without the capacitor to get a baseline.
2. The noise on the power rail with the capacitor to see its effect.

However, as you pointed out, when you place your oscilloscope probe near the capacitor, you're indeed probing not just across the capacitor but also the parallel resistance (which may be the equivalent series resistance (ESR) of the capacitor, any real resistance in the circuit, or any parasitic resistance).

So, what you can do?

1. **Proper probe grounding**: Use a short ground lead on your probe. The longer the ground lead, the more it acts as an antenna, picking up noise. Alternatively, use a spring or ground pin to ensure the shortest possible ground connection.
2. **Use differential probing**: If you have access to a differential probe, it can be very useful as it will measure the voltage difference directly across the capacitor, ignoring common mode voltages.
3. **Watch the bandwidth limit**: Most modern oscilloscopes will allow you to limit the bandwidth. If you're only interested in noise up to a certain frequency, limit the bandwidth to reduce high-frequency noise which might not be relevant to your measurement.
4. **Use a high-resolution mode**: Some oscilloscopes offer a high-resolution mode that can increase the vertical resolution of the scope by using digital signal processing. This can be useful for measuring small signals superimposed on larger DC levels.
5. **Parasitics!**: Be aware of the parasitic inductance and resistance of the bypass capacitor itself. At very high frequencies, a capacitor can act more like an inductor due to its equivalent series inductance (ESL).
6. **Choose the best measurement point**: Make sure to probe as close as possible to the capacitor's terminals to minimize the effect of any parasitic elements present in the traces or connections.

Remember, the oscilloscope will show both the desired signals and undesired noise. Proper probing techniques and understanding of what you're measuring can help you interpret the results correctly. If you find noise that you think shouldn't be there, it's worth double-checking your setup and connections before drawing conclusions.

Good luck;)